# Read/Write Excel with java based API - vogella

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to modify existing excel file with the JAVA Excel API [vogella](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaExcel/article.html), but can't handle it. I found a way to recreate the excel file, but this is not what I want. Could someone to give an advice, hint or share a short example.

I'm sharing what I'm trying to do:

```
    /**
     * Reading external file.
     *
     * @return Record[];
     * @throws IOException;
     * @throws BiffException.
     */
    public Record[] read() throws IOException {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook w;
        Record[] records = null;
        int rowsCount = 0;
        try {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);

            int columnsCount = sheet.getColumns();
            rowsCount = sheet.getRows();
            records = new Record[rowsCount];

            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowsCount; rowIndex++) {
                Record record = new Record(columnsCount);
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsCount; columnIndex++) {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(columnIndex, rowIndex);
                    String value = cell.getContents();
                    record.setRecordData(columnIndex, value);
                }
                records[rowIndex] = record;
            }
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            errorMessage = 1;
        }

        return records;
    }

   /**
    * Writing to existing excel file.
    *
    * @param records;
    * @throws IOException;
    * @throws WriteException;
    * @throws BiffException.
    */
    public void write(Record[] records) throws IOException, WriteException, BiffException {
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        WritableWorkbook writableworkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, workbook, wbSettings);
        WritableSheet excelSheet = writableworkbook.getSheet(0);

        createLabel(excelSheet);
        createContent(excelSheet, records);

        writableworkbook.write();
        writableworkbook.close();
    }
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to figure out what you'd like, by being more specific.  Post what you've done so far, give examples on why what you're getting is not what you want.  Without being specific, this is not really an answerable question.

Comment: @beny23: I want to insert additional custom data to an existing excel file, for instance into the first sheet.

Comment: Need to elaborate on 'can't handle it'

Comment: @Roy Truelove: Now you could see, what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Do you get an exception or does it just silently not work?

Comment: @Roy Truelove: It doesn't throw an exception, it replaces the data and I don't want to replace the data. I want to append the data, for instance in the excel file, sheet 0, there are 10 rows filled up with some data, and I want to place the additional data after the tenth row.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're providing is written *specifically* to overwrite what already exists.. This line:

```
 for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowsCount; rowIndex++)
```

will always start at row 0 and so overwrite everything that's there.

Also, earlier, you're calling:

```
rowsCount = sheet.getRows();
```

Which will tell you how many rows are already populated.  If you start populating after the last populated row, you'll keep everything that's already there.

Comment: Hi! That method is responsible for reading data, which will be populated to the general excel file, and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to create an WritableSheet from an existing one.